# Java - Dekkers Algorithm implementation resulting in two threads in critical section

Tags: java, multithreading, algorithm, jvm, java-threads

I am trying to implement Dekkers Algorithm for a scenario where there are two railroads and there is a point where they both use the same part of the track. Only one train should be allowed to enter this section at once and one train can go through as many times in a row as it would like unless it's both the other trains turn and it is ready to go through.

Below is the code for my implementation for the first railroad track.

```
while (allowed) {
        choochoo();
        setWantToUseTrack(0,true);
        while (getWantToUseTrack(1)) {
            if (getTurn() != 0) {
                setWantToUseTrack(0,false);
                while (getTurn() != 0) {
                    //wait loop
                }
                setWantToUseTrack(0, true);
            }
        }
        //critical section starts
        crossPass();
        //critical section ends
        setTurn(1);
        setWantToUseTrack(0,false);
    }
}
```

Below is the code for my implementation of the second railroad track.

```
while (allowed) {
        choochoo();
        setWantToUseTrack(1,true);
        while (getWantToUseTrack(0)) {
            if (getTurn() != 1) {
                setWantToUseTrack(1,false);
                while (getTurn() != 1) {
                    //wait loop
                }
                setWantToUseTrack(1,true);
            }
        }
        //critical section starts
        crossPass();
        //critical section ends
        setTurn(0);
        setWantToUseTrack(1,false);
    }
```

When this code runs sometimes both trains end up in the critical section at the same time. I cannot see the logical error. Am i missing something from my implementation?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible, that the following happens (just one example):

1. In second track `setWantToUseTrack(1,false);` is invoked.
2. In the first track predicate is checked: `while (getWantToUseTrack(1))`, to the second thread is not stopped in `while` loop.

   This is absolutely feasible, as first track could be stopped by `choochoo();` until (1.) and second track until (2.) occurs.
3. Method `getWantToUseTrack` returns `false` for 0 and 1.

Creating a loop to catch thread until critical section is released is a bit dangerous. You may want to make the section thread-safe by using `synchronized` with `crossPass` definition.